# Oracle ctxsys.context DRG-10599 column is not indexed

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have ctxsys.context index on one column. When i execute below query i give `DRG-10599: column is not indexed` error. I check index and update it.

Query:

```
SELECT s.dsa_id FROM service_search s
  WHERE CONTAINS(s.fld_search, 'someData') >0
```

Index ddl:

```
  CREATE INDEX "ARCHIVE_SER"."IDX_SEARCH_CTX" ON 
    "ARCHIVE_SER"."service_search" ('FLD_SEARCH') 
    INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT"  PARAMETERS ('SYNC ( ON COMMIT)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your index DDL, so it should not have worked. The `('FLD_SEARCH')` column is in single-quotes, which makes it a VARCHAR instead of an identifier. Probably it would be easier to spot errors like this if you didn't use so many double-quotes. :)

This works fine for me.

```
create table service_search (fld_search varchar2(4000));

CREATE INDEX IDX_SEARCH_CTX ON service_search (FLD_SEARCH) 
  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT  PARAMETERS ('SYNC ( ON COMMIT)');

select * from service_search s where contains(s.fld_search, 'someData') > 0;
```